# Invalid property of bean class No property found

Tags: java, spring

This is an app that is running in Prod, but I'm having issues running it in eclipse. Any help would be appreciated.

The bean qewProvider has an autowired property qewSqlMap

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.btec.recon"/>
...
  <bean id="qewProvider" class="com.btec.recon.qewProvider">
    <property name="qewSqlMap" ref="sqlMapClientTemplate"/>
  </bean>

public class qewProvider  
{  
  @Autowired  
    private SqlMapClientTemplate qewSqlMap;  
    ...
```

I get the following exception while trying to execute:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'qewProvider' defined in URL [file:C:/Apps/eclipse-workspace/btc-eclipse/Juno-qew/btc-qew-recon/context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'qewSqlMap' of bean class [com.btec.recon.qewProvider]: No property 'qewSqlMap' found
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
  at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
  at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
  at com.btec.recon.Recon.main(Recon.java:34)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'qewSqlMap' of bean class [com.btec.recon.qewProvider]: No property 'qewSqlMap' found
  at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:382)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
  ... 14 more
```

Comment: It could be that you're missing a setter like `public void setQewSqlMap(SqlMapClientTemplate)` (or maybe the name is misspelled or not in the right case).

Comment: We're using spring @Autowired annotation on the property so setter method is not required.

Comment: It looks like you've got a combination of `@Autowired` in the class, but an explicit `<property>` tag in the XML. As I recall, the explicit property declaration will override the autowired directive and try to set the property using a setter method. As such, try removing the `<property>` from the XML or adding a setter method so you can see if this is what's happening.

Comment: Thanks a bunch neuronaut!!  That fixed it.  The context.xml file checked in has <property> tag but the one on the dev server (and logically in prod too) does not.  Thanks again!